# How can I construct a field of $p^n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I was asked specifically to construct a field of $81$ elements. Can someone explain how the process for this works? And how should I approach more questions like this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: use an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$ over $GF(3)$